# Block showing Parent Taxonomy Term of current Node

Tags: 7, views, taxonomy-terms

Ok my taxonomy is setup like this:

- Holiday Cards
- Trees
- Bears
- Religious

So the goal is to display a node belonging to 'Trees' but in that node I need to have a block that shows the Parent Item of 'Holiday Cards' (along with the description of 'Holiday Cards'.

I have attempted to use views to accomplish this but I keep hitting a wall.  Can someone please walk me through, step-by-step, what I am missing in order to accomplish this seemingly simple task?

Comment: What version of Drupal and Views are you on?

Comment: You should update what solution are trying and where are you stucked ?

Comment: Sorry - I am using Drupal 7 - Views 7.x-3.5.

Comment: I have attempted to create a block of taxonomny terms. Then using Relationships and Contextual filters limite those terms to the parent (relationships) of the current Node (contextual filters).  Everytime I try to invoke the Node ID (nid) contextual filter nothing get shows in my auto preview.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is impossible with the Views module.

To achieve the goal, you can create a block with a relation to the "Holiday Cards" term. Under *Filter criteria* select *Taxonomy term: Name (= Holiday Cards)*.

To display the block only with the content related to another taxonomy term, you can consider to use the [Context](http://drupal.org/project/context) module.

1. Instal the module and turn it on.
2. Go to /admin/structure/context/add and create your new context
3. Under "Conditions" choose your taxonomy term "Trees"
4. Under "Reactions" choose "Blocks"
5. Select your block created in views and place it in appropriate region
6. Save the context

That's it! Your block with relation to "Holiday Cards" will be displayed only with content which is related to "Trees."